# Does Unity use DirectX or OpenGL?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I know java, and i started android-development, but also i want to create 3d game. I've got unity for this, but... It uses directx, right? And what's about android development? It uses directx too? Or it uses opengl instead?

Comment: you can change the Graphics API for each platform if you want, it is under Edit > Project Settings > Player > Other Settings in Unity 2017+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DirectX is for windows/xbox only. It depends on the unit actually. Android is gearing towards Vulcan but it will still support opengl.

This is typically something that you won't need to worry about as Unity already handles it for you if ever you're worried. Of course for more advanced stuff, you will need to know this eventually.

Comment: Any idea what more advanced stuff, I'd need to know about this for ? thank you.

Comment: Well, more of on the render pipeline side and their benefits. Each graphics API handle certain things differently but outputs the same things the same way. Fortunately, Unity just does this for you automatically.

I guess now just thinking about it, you wouldn't need to know any of the stuff at all. You might be more interested if you want to build your own game engine and support multiple graphics api.